# SQL Query Error

Tags: sql, mysql, insert, mysql-error-1064

What is wrong with this Query?

```
INSERT INTO Registration 
  (`Status`, `String`) 
VALUES 
  ('Confirmed', '0') 
WHERE `String` = '". mysql_real_escape_string($user) ."'
```

---

**1A:**

```
UPDATE Registration 
       `Status` = 'Confirmed', 
       `String` = '0' 
 WHERE `String` = '". mysql_real_escape_string($user) ."'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
UPDATE Registration 
   SET `Status` = 'Confirmed', 
       `String` = '0' 
 WHERE `String` = '". mysql_real_escape_string($user) ."'
```

INSERT is for brand-new records; if you are change values associated to an existing value -- you need to use UPDATE.

Reference:

- [UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)
- [INSERT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html)

Answer (score 5):

You don't specify a WHERE clause on an INSERT query, only UPDATE.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense! So, I would need to to this [see 1A on original post]?

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth combing over this page: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html